# Edit and Update functions in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am getting an error which says 
"Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\newXampp\htdocs\testUser\resources\views\Stock\edit.blade.php)"

This is my Controller

```
public function editStock(Stock $id)
    {
        //
        $Stock = Stock::find($id);
        return view('Stock.edit', compact('Stock', 'id'));
        // return response($stock);

    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Stock  $stock
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function updateStock(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'id'=>'required',
            'stock_name'=>'required',
            'stock_qty'=>'required',
            'stock_unit'=>'required',
            'stock_price_per_kg'=>'required',
            'stock_weight_per_qty'=>'required'
        ]);

        $stock = Stock::find($id);
        $stock->stock_name =  $request->get('stock_name');
        $stock->stock_qty = $request->get('stock_qty');
        $stock->stock_unit = $request->get('stock_unit');
        $stock->stock_price_per_kg = $request->get('stock_price_per_kg');
        $stock->stock_weight_per_qty = $request->get('stock_weight_per_qty');
        $stock->save();

        return redirect('/Stock/index/')->with('success', 'Stock updated!');

    }
```

These are my routes

```
//Route for Stock
Route::get('/Stock/createStock/', 'ChicController@createStock')->name('createStock');
Route::post('/Stock/createStock/', 'ChicController@storeStock')->name('storeStock');
Route::get('/Stock/index/', 'ChicController@indexStock')->name('indexStock');
Route::get('/Stock/edit/{id}', 'ChicController@editStock')->name('editStock');
Route::post('/Stock/edit/{id}', 'ChicController@updateStock')->name('updateStock');
Route::delete('/Stock/index/{id}', 'ChicController@destroyStock')->name('deleteStock');
```

This is my edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
        <h1 class="display-3">Update a Stock</h1>

        @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br /> 
        @endif
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('updateStock', $Stock->id) }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="stock_name">Stock Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="stock_name" value={{$Stock->stock_name }} />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="stock_qty">Stock Amount:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="stock_qty" value={{$Stock->stock_qty }} />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="stock_unit">Stock Unit:</label>
                <select id="stock_unit" name="stock_unit" value={{$Stock->stock_unit}}>
                    <option value="Kg">Kg</option>
                    <option value="Qty">Qty</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="stock_price_per_kg">Price Per Kg:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="stock_price_per_kg" value={{$Stock->stock_price_per_kg }} />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="stock_weight_per_qty">Weight Per Qty:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="stock_weight_per_qty" value={{$Stock->stock_weight_per_qty }} />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I have tried everything, but I could not solve the problem. When I try to echo the $id in the edit Controller, it shows the correct $id. Hence, I do not know how to solve this, nor do I know why this is happening.

Comment: The error is indicating that `$Stock` in your edit view is a Collection object, not a model. Is your controller code exactly what you have now? Have you tried doing a `dd($Stock)` in your controller before the view?

Comment: @AkenRoberts Yes, my controller is exactly like the one I posted.
Where would I add this dd($Stock)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `editStock` method you are already receiving an instance of a `Stock` model matching the `id` from the route parameter due to the Implicit Route Model Binding that is taking place. When you pass that `$id` variable to `Stock::find($id)` you are passing a Model which is `Arrayable`. This causes `find` to become `findMany` thinking you are passing many ids. You end up with a Collection because of this:

```
public function editStock(Stock $id)
{
    $Stock = Stock::find($id);
    return view('Stock.edit', compact('Stock', 'id'));
}
```

`$Stock` is a Collection because of passing many to `find`. I would adjust this to only pass the `$id` variable to your view which is the `Stock` that you want.

```
public function editStock(Stock $id)
{
    return view('Stock.edit', [
        'Stock' => $id,
    ]);
}
```

Your view will now have a `Stock` variable which is the `Stock` that you wanted.

[Laravel 5.8 Docs - Routing - Route Model Bindings - Implicit Bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding)